# Run code with locked screen in the background for hours - can it be done?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I lack of information in what is exactly happening when my application runs in the background and the screen is locked. Some setup.

I have created a CLLocationManager and started it, also I have registered a handler from altimeter updates. Of course background modes are on and selected background fetch and location updates, added in the Plist the required keys. What I care most is to get the location update and also do some work in the altimeter update handler. In the handler I have some logic and then I use NSURLSession to POST the values in my REST HTTP server.

From my testings I've noticed that since the user started the application allowed location updates and I started the location manager and altimeter updates my altimeter handler is invoked every second for about 20-25 seconds so I get my readings in the server.

I also noticed that if I open the application but don't initiate the whole process in the ViewController but simulate background fetch it doesn't seem to invoke the altimeter handler. Why I can't start the location manager when the background fetch is simulated and never started so far?

What are the limitations when the screen is locked after 10-15 minutes, is Apple background modes not working when application is suspended?

It is not terminated by the system cause as soon as I unlock it it will send me some messages to the server, like it kept it is in memory paused and the handler will start again to update. Also I found this article here, http://mobileoop.com/background-locatio ... -for-ios-7 claiming this is working for 3 hours, I don't like the solution but I was about to try, though it seems that it doesn't work for everyone the same, so I have doubts. He is using the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier which I've seen in RW article before, http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/back ... ng-for-ios, but haven't embedded yet cause I'm not sure if you are anyway able to send POST requests and updates when the screen is locked "forever" and maybe that time is sufficient if system won't allow you to do it anyway.

If the application stops responding, meaning the handler is not invoked, if I simulate background fetch the handler run 2-3 times but doesn't initiate the NSURLSession POST request.

The code.

```
// WEELog is just a wrapper function, you could change it to NSLog removing the log level 

- (void) commonInitialization
    {
    self.readingsModel = [WEEReadingsModel new];
    self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
        {
        WEELog(DebugLogLevel, @"I should request location now");
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
    self.altimeter = [CMAltimeter new];
    self.isAltimeterAvailable = [CMAltimeter isRelativeAltitudeAvailable];
    }

- (void) start:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
    {
    UIBackgroundFetchResult fetchResult = UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData;
    if (self.altimeter == nil ||
        self.locationManager == nil)
        {
        [self commonInitialization]; 
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
        if (self.isAltimeterAvailable)
            {
            [self.altimeter startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAltitudeData *altitudeData, NSError *error)
                {
                UIBackgroundFetchResult fetchResult = error == nil ? UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData : UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed;
                if (error == nil)
                    {
                    double previousPressureInInchesOfMercury = self.readingsModel.pressureInInchesOfMercury ? self.readingsModel.pressureInInchesOfMercury.doubleValue : 0.0;
                    [self.readingsModel appendWithAltitudeData:altitudeData];
                    if (self.readingsModel.pressureInInchesOfMercury.doubleValue != previousPressureInInchesOfMercury)
                        {
                        fetchResult = UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData;
                        WEELog(DebugLogLevel, @"New readings to save %@", self.readingsModel.toJSONString);
                        [[WEEServiceRepository sharedInstance] sendReadings:self.readingsModel withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error, NSURLResponse *response)
                            {
                            NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                            WEELog(DebugLogLevel, @"Called my completion handler: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li - %@", (long)httpResponse.statusCode, [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:httpResponse.statusCode]]);
                            }];
                        }
                    }
                else
                    {
                    WEELog(ErrorLogLevel, @"Error in altimeter handler: %@", error);
                    fetchResult = UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed;
                    }
                }];
        }
   }

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
    {
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    if (location != nil)
        {
        WEELog(DebugLogLevel, @"Location update");
        [self.readingsModel appendWithLocation:location];
        }
    }

// Web service call

- (void) sendReadings:(WEEReadingsModel*)readingsModel withCompletionHandler:(WebServiceCompletion)completionHandler
    {
    WEEReachability* reachability = [WEEReachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    if (reachability.isReachable &&
        readingsModel)
        {
        NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ServerUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0f];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSData* originalData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@", readingsModel.toJSONString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:originalData];

        if (!self.defaultSessionConfiguration)
            {
            self.defaultSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.defaultSessionConfiguration delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
            }

        NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
            {
            WEELog(DebugLogLevel, @"DataTask completion handler is invoked!");
            if (completionHandler)
                {
                completionHandler(error, response);
                }
            }];
        [dataTask resume];
        }
    }
```

I haven't tried using silent push notifications yet, do you think it would be a proper solution to wake up my app even if the app is locked and as I know it will run some code even if the app is closed right?

So I guess the information I miss most is for how much time the system will let me work with these APIs when I'm trying to use the in location updates, altimeter updates in the background and when the screen is locked? Is it specific or the system will decide how long? Is there a way I miss to make my app executing this code for ~hours?

Answer (score 0):

Start Music/Audio(may be silent) in Background. This will keep your application awake, so that you can achieve whatever you want.

Comment: This will make your application rejected from Apple Store.